# What do I do for dependencies installing wine1.7 on 14.04

Tags: apt, 14.04, wine, package-management, dpkg

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7   
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.19-0ubuntu2~trusty2) but it is not         installable
       Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                   kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
       Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
user@chrubuntu:~$
```

Trying to install wine1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, and i'm not sure what this means, help is greatly appreciated. I already ran `sudo apt-get updat`e and get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

So I run `apt-get update` and:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

This is all very stressing because I have been trying to get Wine for the past week and had to reinstall and IT STILL WON'T WORK.

Comment: Make sure you do `sudo apt-get update`, if you forget the `sudo` you get the "Permission denied" errors you see.

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386` say?

Comment: user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
[sudo] password for user: 
user
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine1.7-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine1.7-i386' has no installation candidate
That's what it says. I took other measures though... i'm not sure what I did.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you are missing i386 support. You might want to try adding it.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 0):

The message about duplicate sources is just a warning, and can safely be ignored. Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

it will (attempt to) install all missing dependencies to "repair" your packages (the `-f` is for "fix").

Comment: Did not work :( Thanks for trying

Comment: Well, what did it do instead of working?

Comment: It said 0 newly installed, 0 newly fixed, and 0 something else. Something like that but yea, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

If after doing this you get a message about duplicate wine entries, try running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ubuntu -r
sudo apt-get update
```

Please note, the -r at the end tells add-apt-repository to remove a ppa, rather than adding one.

Also, you may want to try running your favorite text editor as a root user to remove the Google entries from /etc/apt/sources.list (for example, `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`). Save the file, and run `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use your favorite text editor to open `/etc/apt/sources.list` (make a backup first)
2. Change

   ```
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
   ```

   to

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
   ```
3. Run these commands

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Finally, install wine using aptitude

   ```
   sudo aptitude --full-resolver -f install wine1.7
   ```